# I am having trouble calling another method

Tags: c#, methods, syntax-error

I am not sure if I am doing it right, but I am trying to get the CalculateGrossPay method to run when I click the CalculateBttn_Click button during run time. However, I get random syntax errors that constantly change for whatever reason. I do not change any to make that happen. I am supposed to make a separate method to calculate the gross pay.

```
private void CalculateBttn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  CalculateGrossPay(decimal hours, decimal rate);

    }




    private decimal CalculateGrossPay(decimal hours, decimal rate)
    {
        decimal result=0.00m;
        decimal standardHours= 0.00m;
        decimal overtimeHours=0.00m;



        if (hours > 40)
        {

            overtimeHours = (hours - 40) * ( (rate) * 1.5m);
            standardHours = 40 * rate;

            DisplayOutPut.Text = name+ NameTextBox.Text + ""; 

            DisplayOutPut.Text = "Gross Pay:" + result;
        }
        else
        {
            standardHours = hours * rate;
            DisplayOutPut.Text = "Hours:" + HoursTextBox.Text;
            DisplayOutPut.Text = "Rate:" + RateTextBox.Text;
        }
        result = standardHours + overtimeHours;
        return result;
```

}

Comment: your call is wrong, pass values there like: `CalculateGrossPay(7M,8M)` or whatever your values are.

Answer (score 4):

Methods in C# that specify parameters need to be called with Parameters. `CalculateGrossPay` defines 2 Parameters the hours and the rate as `decimal` values.

Therefore you need to call `CalculateGrossPay` with two `decimal` values as Parameters (see example).

Please visit the following sites for more information:

[Methods MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/wew5ytx4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx%20%27Methods%20MSDN%27)

[Variables MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/wew5ytx4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

---

Example:

```
CalculateGrossPay(10.1,0.4);
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is in the way you are calling the method. You should the call to your method to something like  this:

```
decimal hours = 1;
decimal rate = 5;

CalculateGrossPay(hours, rate);
```

The values of hours and rate can be hardcoded or you can read them from the user interface.

Comment: @Undefined in your code you are already using things like DisplayOutput.Text. I suppose that's a label or something? You also have textbox controls that can be used for input. You can read the string values from code and convert them to a decimal. Try reading MSDN to find samples and use search engines to look for other tutorials on the internet. If you  have specific questions you can always come to Stackoverflow.